# snapshot, bundledoc and epstopdf

Tags: epstopdf

I am using `epstopdf` package to convert on the fly `eps` images to `pdf`. However, the `snapshot` package and `bundledoc` do not keep track of the original `eps` file but only of the included `pdf`.

Is there any way to improve this behavior?

Comment: `bundledoc` has an `--include` switch, which 'instructs `bundledoc` to include in the archive all all of the files matching **filespec**, even if they're not referenced in the .dep file'.  (Try `man bundledoc` on a unix-y machine.)  This should work, but without seeing how you're calling `bundledoc`, it's hard to give better advice.  I'd add it to the `.cfg`, personally....

Comment: Jon, Thanks for your comment.I am calling bundledoc with: bundledoc --config=/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/bundledoc/texlive-unix.cfg  --exclude=.sty  --exclude .def --exclude=.fd --exclude=.clo --exclude=.cfg --exclude=.mkii --exclude=.def --verbose --include="*.svg" test.dep  However this approach does not work for two reasons:  1) only works if the svg file is in the same directory as the .dep file  2) I only want to bundle the files needed and not all the others.  Fabio. Sorry but I can't figure out how to break a line :-(

Comment: I don't follow. (1) Can't you specify a path for `--include` just as you are for `--config`? (2) With all these `--excludes`, I'm not sure what files are left to bundle.  Wouldn't it be easier to use something like `tar`?

Comment: Jon thanks for your reply. In regard to 1) I did not think about including a path. I will try that. However this means I will probably include files that are not required by the document. In regard to 2) I was trying to only grab .tex and images files but they are scattered over several directories (and several users).

Comment: Ah, well, `--include="*.svg"` is explicitly asking for *all* `.svg` files, so I'm not sure what the best solution would be in that case.  As for (2), maybe a combination of `find` and `tar` would still work better.  I don't project split files into multiple (not hierarchically related?) directories, so I've never had to worry about this sort of thing.  Note also that the package author reads `comp.text.tex`, so you might have some luck asking there.